# ksh : Need to delete multiple directories quickly and reliably

Tags: fork, parallel-processing, ksh, wait, rm

I have many directories and need to delete them periodically with minimum time.
Additionally for each directories delete status need to know i.e whether deleted successfully or not.
I need to write on the ksh . Could you please help me out.

The sample code which I am using, in which I tried launching `rm-rf` in the background, is not working.

```
for var1 in 1...10
rm -rf <DIR> &
pid[var1]=$!
done

my_var=1
for my_var in 1...var1
wait $pid[my_var]
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
  echo falied
else
 echo passed
fi
done
```

Answer (score 1):

You are out of luck.  **The bottleneck here is the filesystem,** and you are very unlikely to find a filesystem that performs *atomic* operations (like directory deletion) in *parallel*.  No amount of fiddling with shell code is going to make the OS or the filesystem do its job faster.  There is only one disk, and if every deletion requires a write to disk, it is going to be slow.

Your best bet is to switch to a journaling filesystem that does deletions quickly.  I have had good  luck with XFS deleting large files (10-40GB) quickly, but I have not tried deleting directories.  In any case, **your path to improved performance lies in finding the right filesystem, not the right shell script.**

Answer (score 0):

This is generally the form that your script should take, with corrections for the serious errors in syntax. However, as **Norman** noted, it's not going to do what you want. Also, `wait` isn't going to work in a loop like you seem to intend.

```
# this script still won't work
find . -type d | while read dir
# or: for dir in ${dirs[@]}
do
    rm -rf $dir &
    pid[++var1]=$!
done

for my_var in {1...$var1}
do
    wait ${pid[my_var]}
    if [ $? -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo failed
    else
        echo passed
    fi
done
```